# Turkish characters blocks admin panel in Codeigniter(FUEL_CMS)

Tags: php, fuelcms

I am writing a site with fuel_cms(content management system)  . My problem is that when i use turkish characters like "ı,ö" in the edit panels,  admin panel does not view the text after editing. Is there anyway to make fuel-php. accept turkish special characters in?

edit : I had some mails with the creators of fuel cms. Even the admin panel links does not work with some turkish characters . We could not find a solution.

Comment: "when i use turkish characters like "ı,ö" admin panel does not show up"....can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the problem with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable CI to accept UTF-8.

CI guru Phil Sturgeon has a blog post on this:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/08/utf-8-support-for-codeigniter